# C++ Vectors, "=" Operator, Undefined behaviour

Tags: c++

I am revisiting C++ after years and I am currently relearning arrays and vectors.

The `operator []` can cause **undefined behavior** when one attempts to access an index outside of the size of a vector.
Now, I am worried about using the `=` operator for vectors of two different sizes because it throws no error when doing so.

In the following resources the "undefined behaviour" is mentioned in the first paragraph for `operator []`.

- [https://cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/operator[]/](https://cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/operator%5B%5D/)
- https://cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/operator=/

For the `=` operator it states the vector's size is modified accordingly, but I am simply unsure about vocabulary and whether that means I do not have to worry about undefined behaviour here.
Disclaimer: I do not understand the last paragraph "Exception safety" for the `=` operator.

Is there a check to find out whether or not I have to expect undefined behavior for this case?

Comment: Side note: Stop reading cplusplus.com and start reading cppreference.com as your primary C+ reference site. The former is full of errors and inacuracies, the latter is much better - more accurate and correct.

Comment: "Is there a check to find out whether or not I have to expect undefined behaviour for this" - In general, the only check is to "read the standard".

Comment: As I see it, you asked two unrelated questions: one about undefined behavior in `operator[]`, and another about what `operator=` really does. Here you are expected to ask just one question. If these two questions are closely related, then asking both is a good idea, but I think they are unrelated. If you have 2 questions, just make 2 posts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Now, I am worried about using the "=" operator for vectors of two different sizes because it throws no error when doing so.

Using the assignment operator is safe. The `vector` you assign to will have the same size and values as the `vector` that you copy or move from.

Comment: Thank you. I would upvote it, but I do not have the reputation for that. However I can accept the answer in a mere 6 minutes! This site is strange : )

Comment: @IcedPigeon You're welcome! Yeah, it's a bit odd that you can't vote on answers to your own question unless you have 50 rep (I think), but, that's the way it is. :-)

Comment: @IcedPigeon • you can `v = v2;` to **copy** a vector, or you can `v = std::move(v2);` to **move** a vector (assuming that `v2` is no longer used, so it can have it's innards transplanted into `v`).

Answer (score 1):

Elaborating slightly on what Ted Lyngmo has said in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77856602/15261315), let's consider starting to implement our own simple `vec` class. If we honor the [rule of three/five/zero](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) we implement copy and move constructors and assignment operators.

In the event that we copy, the allocated size, size, and array are copied. The old array is deleted and replaced with one allocated based on the size of the source vector. The information about the original array is overwritten. There is no concern that the original `vec<T>` object will not have enough space.

In the event of a move, we can see why moving is so powerful. No new allocation and no copying is involved. We simply migrate the pointer, so that the new object manages the memory already allocated. The information about that memory is copied, and the other object is updated to reflect that it's not managing any memory. As such, there is no worry about the destination object not having sufficient space.

```cpp
#include <algorithm>

template <typename T>
class vec {
    std::size_t allocated;
    std::size_t size;
    T *arr;

public:
    vec()
    : allocated(1), size(0),
      arr(new T[allocated])
    { }

    ~vec() { delete[] arr; }

    // Copy constructor
    vec(const vec<T>& other)
    : allocated(other.allocated),
      size(other.size),
      arr(new T[allocated])
    {
        std::copy(
            other.arr, other.arr + other.size,
            arr
        );
    }

    // Copy assignment
    vec<T>& operator=(const vec<T>& other) {
        if (this == &other) return *this;

        delete[] arr;
        allocated = other.allocated;
        size = other.size;
        arr = new T[allocated];
        std::copy(
            other.arr, other.arr + other.size,
            arr
        );

        return *this;
    }

    // Move constructor
    // No allocation, no copying!
    vec(vec<T>&& other)
    : allocated(other.allocated),
      size(other.size),
      arr(nullptr)
    {
        other.allocated = 0;
        other.size = 0;
        std::swap(other.arr, arr);
    }

    // Move assignment
    // Again, no allocation, no copying!
    vec<T>& operator=(vec<T>&& other) {
        if (this == &other) return *this;

        allocated = other.allocated;
        size = other.size;
        arr = arr.other;

        other.allocated = 0;
        other.size = 0;
        other.arr = nullptr;

        return *this;
    }

    // Lots of other stuff to make this actually useful...
};
```